# How to save values in associative array?

Tags: python

I am new to pyhton and want to get URLs from a MySQL table, process the items and save it back to the database. This works if I have it within the results query:

```
    results = curb.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        response2 = requests.get(row[0], stream=True)
        response2.raw.decode_content = True
        image2 = Image.open(response2.raw)
        hash2 = str(imagehash.average_hash(image2))
        width, height = image2.size

        curb.execute("""
                UPDATE
                    table
                SET
                    WIDTH = %s,
                    HEIGHT = %s,
                    CHECKSUM = %s
                WHERE
                    URL = %s

            """, (
            width,
            height,
            hash2,
            row[0]
        )
        )
```

I know this is not how it should be, my question is how can I pull those 4 values into an associated array so I can loop through it in another loop?

Something of the like:

```
my_list = []
# get data
for row in results:
    width = my_list['url...']['width'] = 200

# write data
for item in  my_list:
     ...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `my_list['url...']['width']`? you have declared `my_list` as a list this is invalid

Comment: I inow, this is just an idea. What is the right way to do it? Should it be a dict?

Comment: your solution looks fine, what is the problem i don't understand? do you need those values in any other place?

Comment: Well the sql within the results loop sometimes failes, so it never commits. I want to therefore seperate getting values and processing them. So I can do try catch and commit after each data update.

Comment: try storing results in a new list so you can access those values from the list

Comment: Well this is what the question is all about :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can save them as a list of tuples:

```
    my_list.append((row[0], width, height, hash2))
```

or as a list of dicts

```
    my_list.append( {'url': row[0], 'width': width, 'height': height, 'hash2': hash2})
```

What you propose in your second snipped is a dict of dicts:

```
my_list = {}
for row in results:
    ...
    my_list[row[0]] = { 'width': width, 'height': height, 'hash2': hash2 }
```

All are valid approaches.  It depends on what works for you.